# How to install Windows Phone 8 workload in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have installed Visual Studio 2017 in my computer and after installing when I tried to open my Windows Phone 8 project, I got an error that Windows Phone 8 SDK is missing. So, I right-click on the project and clicked on install missing feature but it shows 0 Kb every time. So, can some suggest me steps to install Windows Phone 8 SDK and tools/templates in Visual Studio 2017? I also tried to install Standalone SDK but it was still giving me some JSON Package error and in Visual Studio it was showing **my project name.csproj error: Operation Cancelled**.

Please suggest some solution so I can work on my Windows Phone 8 project in VS2017.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-references-in-a-project this may help you.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn954974.aspx you may also go through this link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like Microsoft removed the support for developing Windows Store apps that targets Windows and Windows Phone 8/8.1 from Visual Studio 2017.

See this [Visual Studio 2017 compatibility](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2017-compatibility-vs) page. In short, it says "Windows Store app development is not available."

You can help changing Microsoft mind by [voting](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/18599338-visual-studio-2017-add-support-for-windows-store) to bring it back.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're on Windows 10. The Windows Phone 8 SDK has a hard system requirement for Windows 8:

> Supported Operating System
>
> - Windows 8, Windows 8 Pro
> - Operating system type:
>
>   - Windows 8 64-bit (x64) client versions

<sup>https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471</sup>

Comment: No, I am using Windows 10 since 1 year and I was using VS 2015 in which this was working perfectly fine. I think Windows Phone 8 SDK is not compatible with VS2017 but I am not sure.